# React + .jsx + Spread Operator -- Add a Style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a React element (courtesy of the excellent Downshift library) that looks like this:

```
<mySearchResults
    {...{
        inputValue,
        selectedItem,
        highlightedIndex,
        getItemProps,
    }}
/>
```

I need to add a .jsx style to it:

```
 style: styles.searchResultsContainer
```

I've tried a couple ways of adding it, including:

```
<mySearchResults
    {...{
        inputValue,
        selectedItem,
        highlightedIndex,
        getItemProps,
        style: styles.searchResultsContainer
    }}
/>
```

It builds and runs without errors, but it doesn't seem to get the styles into the element.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: that should be correct. Are you sure your `mySearchResults` component is set up to accept a `style` prop?

Comment: You solved it.  I'm used to MUI components that take style props -- in this case, I have total control over the component and must implement the style myself. Thanks! If you would like to post your reply as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be correct. Are you sure your `mySearchResults` component is set up to accept a style prop?

Comment: Please rephrase this to sound less like a comment/question and more like an answer. Maybe add documentation of the component to show that it does not accept a `style` prop. https://github.com/paypal/downshift#basic-props